# How to get context for BaseAdapter in Android

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-context

I have a class named `BinderData` which extends `BaseAdapter`. I want to get the base class context. I tried to use `getContext()` but that doesn't work in case of `BaseAdapter`.

How can I get the Context of this class?

Answer (score 32):

**One more solution-**

If you have a parent, you can directly access the context like so-

```
 public class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            LayoutInflater inflater;

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if(inflater == null){
                Context context = parent.getContext();
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                }
                ...
                ...

                return convertView;
            }

    }
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. @Karakuri's answer is inefficient.

Comment: you saved my day god bless you. this worked like a charm

Answer (score 14):

Make a constructor that takes a `Context` as one of its arguments and store it in a private variable.

```
public class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    /* ... other methods ... */
}
```

Comment: I suggest you get a firm handle on Java basics before you start tackling Android specifically.

Comment: It is setting context as null.

Comment: Are you passing it null? You need to pass it a valid Context.

Comment: @Karakuri hey I also get context as a null :(

Comment: For those getting Context null check how you are creating Adapter object. If you creating it from Activity's onCreate method you can simply pass `getApplicationContext()` or `this`.

Answer (score 6):

```
Context context = parent.getContext();
```