# Listview: Only one list item with multiple textviews

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I need to show multiple text views in only one list item and the rest of the list view items will have just one textview.

How do I achieve this? Any samples or tutorials you can point me at?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own adapter:

BaseAdapter already provieds methods for working with different View types (different layout for list item cells) and to effektivly recycle views:

- getViewTypeCount(): The count of how many different Views (layouts) are present.
- getItemViewType(): Returns a integer to identify the view type of the item in the cell. Note the internally BaseAdapter implementation uses an array. Therefore your values returned here must be from 0 to n. You are not allowed to skip indexes.

  public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  ```
  private final int VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
  private final int VIEW_TYPE_4_TEXTS = 1;

  /**
   * The inflater for
   */
  protected LayoutInflater inflater;
  protected Context context;

  public MyAdapter(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
      this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {
      // There are two view types
      return 2;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if (position == 0)
          return VIEW_TYPE_4_TEXTS;
      else
          return VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      int type = getItemViewType(position);
      if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = newView(type, parent);
      }
      bindView(position, type, convertView);
      return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0; // replace it with your id, if you have stable ids in your
                  // adapter
  }

  /** Inflates the correct view accorind the view type **/
  public View newView(int type, ViewGroup parent) {

      if (VIEW_TYPE_4_TEXTS == type) {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_with_4_textviews,
                  parent, false);
          view.setTag(new ViewHolder4TextViews(view)); // ViewHolder pattern

          return view;
      }

      // Otherwise its a normal item with VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL
      View view = inflater
              .inflate(R.layout.your_normal_layout, parent, false);
      view.setTag(new NormalViewHolder(view)); // ViewHolder pattern

      return view;

  }

  /** Bind the data for the specified {@code position} to the {@code view}. */
  public void bindView(int position, int type, View view) {

      if (VIEW_TYPE_4_TEXTS == type) {
          // set the 4 text view values
          ViewHolder4TextViews holder = (ViewHolder4TextViews) view.getTag();

          holder.textview1.setText("...");
          holder.textview2.setText("...");
          holder.textview3.setText("...");
          holder.textview4.setText("...");

      } else {
          // VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL
          NormalViewHolder holder = (NormalViewHolder) view.getTag();

          holder.textview.setText("...");
      }

  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom adapter for you list and edit the getView function:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    [...]

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parentView) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if(position < 1) {
                /* Inflate a layout with 4 textview */
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_4_textview_layout, parentView, false);

            } else {
                /* Inflate a layout with 1 textview */
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_1_textview_layout, parentView, false);

            }

            return view;

    }

    [...]

}
```

Take care about pass Context context to MyListAdapter in constructor like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594557/how-to-get-context-for-baseadapter-in-android)

Comment: your code will always recreate for each listview item, its not performant.  Checkout my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in your adapter...some thing like this.
@position 1: "blank" view will be diplayed
@rest positions: "triplistrow" will bw displayed

```
   @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) 
  {         
      View rowView = convertView;
      if(position !=1)
      {
      if (rowView == null) 
      {
          LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
          rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.triplistrow, null);
          ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

          viewHolder.no = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TVTripNo);
          viewHolder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TVTripName);
          viewHolder.date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TVTripDate);

          rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
       }
      }
      else
      {
          LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
          rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.triplistrow, null);
          ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

          rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
      }

      if(position!=1)
      {
      final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();  

      holder.no.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
      holder.name.setText(values.get(position).name);
      holder.date.setText(values.get(position).fromdate + " to " + values.get(position).tilldate);

      }else
      {



      }


    return rowView;
  }
```